# css background color on transparent image

Tags: css, image, photoshop, transparent

I don't know how to make the background color on my player image to be blue.

I've tried:

css: `background-color: transparent blue`

Here is a link to the page:

[Homepage](http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/)

Can someone instruct me? Do I need to use `photoshop` and make it blue?

UPDATE:

I was referring to just the image that has the player icon on it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.fancy_video img {
    background-color: #33d;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
}
```

For IE9+ only as suggested by @showdev with transparent background:

```
.fancy_video img {
    background-color: rgba(51,51,221,.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: +1 great solution. For transparency, I'd suggest `background-color: rgba(51,51,221,.5)`. [Browser compatability IE9+.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors)

Comment: @jkushner The answer exactly targets the image that has the player icon on it :)

Comment: @showdev that works but it makes a square over the circle. how do i encompass it directly in the circle?

Comment: Credit goes to Arbel, not me. Were you commenting on the other answer? For reference, here's a [sample fiddle of Arbel's solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6f62hp6p/2/). I added a `:hover` state, just for kicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an html element with both a background image and a background color (in CSS). Therefore the easiest way to accomplish what you're going for is to have an element that lies directly on top of the image that has a blue tint on it using opacity or RGBA in CSS.

For example:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/wyj3oj93/]
```